# How to send json post request using jersey client in java

Tags: java, jersey-client

I am trying to send a json Post using Jersey-client in java but it is not working.

Code which is not working

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("userName", "euler");
                jsonObject.put("password", "password");
    Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/ldap/webapi/Auth").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(jsonObject));

                    String result = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

For the above code i am getting the result string as (false)

Now i created a model POJO class user.java with userName and password as variables and sent user object as json and it started working.

Code which is working

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    User user = new User();
                user.setUserName("euler");
                user.setPassword("password");
                Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8181/ldapAuth/webapi/Auth").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(user));

                String result = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

For the above code i am getting the result string as (true).

I need to send the POST as json object and not a model class which is converted into JSON.

REST API:

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public  Status Login(User user){ 


            AuthManager manager = new AuthManager();
            return manager.Authenticate(user);


    }
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.wooqer.com.ldapAuth</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.wooqer.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>ldapAuth</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ldapAuth</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>ldapAuth</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.6</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: can you add the web.xml ? may be you just need disable the pojo mapping feature.

Comment: @Reddy , You need web.xml file or pom.xml file?

Comment: add them both if you can.

Comment: put appropriate logs and see where its not working, also check server separately by posting request from a browser http client like postman

Comment: @Reddy I have added pom.xml and web.xml

Comment: @vels4j I tried from POSTMAN and it was working.

Comment: Take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188753/retrieve-jsonobject-in-post-with-jersey