# how to pass json and get json reponse in jersey 2.x and also "escapeForwardSlashAlways": true is getting displayed as response in jersey 2.x and

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson, jersey-2.0

I am working on a rest project using jersey in java. The jersey website https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html is not accessible to look on the documentation for jersey 2.x , so i am posting this question,

I have a jersey project that uses jersey 1.x. I have a POJO class for Student

```
public class Student
{
    private String rollno;

    private String name;

    public String getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }

    public void setRollno(String rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I have a resource class for post method as below,

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createStudent(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response, JSONObject jsonData) throws JSONException {
        // -- process data
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("message", "created successful");
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(json).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
```

Below is the web.xml entry for jersey 1.x,

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>my.package</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Using the postman, i am provide the input data to json as,

```
{
  "rollno" : "STD01",
  "name" : "XXX"
}
```

The above setup works fine for jersey 1.x and i was able to get the response message as **created successful**. Now i have tried to migrate this project to jersey2.x and performed the below changes,

**web.xml :**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>my.package</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

**pom.xml :** (imported the below dependency)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b03</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now i executed the same project and got the below error,

```
Unrecognized field "rollno" (class org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject), not 
    marked as ignorable (one known property: "escapeForwardSlashAlways"])
     at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.intrnal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@42512d97; line: 2, column: 15] (through reference chain: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject["rollno"])
```

So i have changed the parameter for POST resource class and POJO class as below,

**Student.class** :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Student
{
    private String rollno;

    private String name;

    public String getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }

    public void setRollno(String rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Resource class :**

```
 @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response createStudent(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response, Student student) throws JSONException {
            // -- process data
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("message", "created successful");
            return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(json).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        }
```

After using the POJO class instead of JSONObject, the @POST method got hit and  the exception gone away. But i was getting the response as

```
{
  "escapeForwardSlashAlways": true
}
```

If i change the return type as Student and set the values, i was able to return the json. But i was not able to return the jsonobject that i have created for the response.

My question is why the project that worked in jersey 1.x with the JSONObject is not working in jersey 2.x ?

Do i need to always use the POJO class to get the input data from client?

How can i return a customized json as response instead of POJO ?

Kindly advice me. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Documentation link : https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. but is there any solution for this use case ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188753/retrieve-jsonobject-in-post-with-jersey

Comment: I cannot tell why it is not working. But try to set `entity(json.toString())` for the return.